# Field shadowed by local variable from the point of view of an anonymous class

Tags: java, shadowing

I'm trying to run this code:

```
class A {
  int x = 123;
  public void f(int x) {
    new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(x);
      }
    }.run();
  }
  static {
    A a = new A();
    a.f(33);
  }
}
```

But it's giving me an error:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:6: local variable x is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
        System.out.println(x);
                           ^
1 error
```

The `x` argument isn't `final`, so it shouldn't be accessible from the anonymous class, yet the code fails to compile. It looks like the `println` line is trying to use the `x` argument instead of the `x` field. Why? How can I tell it I want the `x` field?

Comment: @Makoto This is not a duplicate of that question. That question involves accessing non-final variables, not shadowing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
A.this.x
```

Since the anonymous `Runnable` class is an inner class of the `A` class.

The concept of shadowing determines that `x` in

```
System.out.println(x);
```

is referring to the local method parameter variable `x`, but that is not `final` so you can't access it within the anonymous class, not in Java 7 and below at least. You can in Java 8, which may be confusing.

<sub>Don't use the same name for your variables in the same compilation unit.</sub>

Comment: Yep, that's it. Beat me to it. 1+

Comment: @JasonC I'm sure there's one somewhere. People that ask don't usually know the names of the concepts involved so it is kind of hard to find.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, I found one right when you replied, a little down the "java inner shadowed" search result list. Not too obvious unless your search-fu is strong. *flex*

Comment: What's a compilation unit? Got a link about the Java 8 change?

Comment: @Dog A compilation unit is a single file that gets compiled. So a single `.java` file. As for Java 8, see the tutorial on [Local Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) on `Accessing Members of an Enclosing Class`. I don't have the link to the JLS now. Please don't ask for it :|. I'll find it if you really want.